# The smallest amount

Tags: probability, combinatorics, puzzle

Using a pool of problems, 20 tests will be formed.
-Every test should have the same number of problems.
-Any problem should be included in at most 10 tests.
-For every 5 tests, there should be at least 2 problems common to all of them.
What can be the minimum number of problems in this pool?

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but an approach.  Make groups of 10 tests and put two unique problems on each test of the group.  There are ${20 \choose 5}=15504$ groups of tests that must share two problems.  Each group of $10$ has ${10 \choose 5}=252$ five element subsets, so it will take at least $\frac {15504}{252}\approx 61.5$ groups of $10$ to cover all the five element subsets of $20$ in this way.  This way we should be able to get by with not many more than $124$ questions.  The fact that it doesn't divide evenly shows we can't have a perfect set of groups, so that each $5$ element subset of the $20$ is in only one group, but we should be able to get close.  Each test will be in about half the groups, so the equal number of problems per test will be satisfied.  Otherwise make a few more problems to equalize.

This doesn't prove that you can form the groups to minimize the overlap, but generally it doesn't take much "wiggle room" to make these possible.

Comment: First of all I really appreciate your help, but I couldn't understand your approach entirely. It may be because of my poor math knowledge or my poor english. Whatever I do, I can't deal with that "every 5 tests have 2 problems common to all of them" situation. I try to use every problem in 10 different tests, to lower the number of problems. But I'm not getting any closer to finding an answer.

Comment: For example, one group of 10 tests would be numbers 1 through 10.  Assign problems 1 and 2 to each of these.  This accounts for the required two problems for the groups 12345, 12689, and 250 others.  Another group would be 11 through 20.  Assign problems 3 and 4 to each of these tests and we have covered another 252 groups of 5.  Now assign problems 5 and 6 to all the odd number tests and so on.  We need to find a batch of 10 element subsets of $[1,20]$ such that every 5 element subset of $[1,20]$ is contained in at least one.

Comment: I think I'm getting it now. Here is what I wonder. Considering 124, why cant we say 13 for sure as the answer?

Comment: 124 comes from 62 different groups of 10, each getting two questions.  I don't know where 13 comes from (is it 124/10 rounded up?)  But we might not be able to cover all 15504 groups of 5 with only 62-there might be too much overlap.  For example, if the third group were all the odds, it would have 13579 as a subgroup, which was already covered by the first.

Comment: I know it's been a long time since i asked this question, but i want to say that this question may have a mathematical solution which i have no idea about because of my lack of mathematical skills. If you try to do like you said, by assigning problems, at the end you have to check every 5 group. And 15504 is too many. Also, even if you check all 15504, you can't be sure if it's the minimum answer.

Comment: @Taner Whether $15504$ is too many to check depends on your technique.  A computer could run through that in no time.  I agree it is too many to check by hand.  You are also correct that it wouldn't prove you have the minimum.  Maybe somebody could come up with a cleverly structured solution, but I haven't.  I hoped this might prompt some thinking along those lines.